# Why do i get this error ? Pygame.error: couldn't open block.jpg

Tags: python, image, pygame, codeblocks

I don't understand why i keep getting this error whenever i run this block of code,

```
def on_init(self):
    pygame.init()
    self._display_surf = pygame.display.set_mode((self.windowWidth,self.windowHeight), pygame.HWSURFACE)

    pygame.display.set_caption('Pygame pythonspot.com example')
    self._running = True
    self._image_surf = pygame.image.load("block.jpg").convert()
    self._apple_surf = pygame.image.load("block.jpg").convert()
```

i would like to understand how and where this error comes from  and how to fix it

Comment: where have you save this image file?

Answer (score 1):

try to add the full path to the image file, like this:

```
self._image_surf = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Users\python\block.jpg").convert()
```

Hope it help, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to provide the full path to the image you must make sure that the image is in the same folder/directory as the code.